# Pick conditional values from ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have this struct created.

```
struct MedItem: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID() //Generates a unique string for each item listed below
    let medThumbnail: String
    let medTitle: String
    let medDose: String
    let medDoseval: String
    let purpose: String
    let takeAt: String
    let refillDate: String
    let refillRem: String
    
}
```

With this data added:

```
struct MedData {

    static let mListData = [

        MedItem(medThumbnail: "Levo", medTitle: "Levothyroxine", medDose: "15", takeAt: "8 am", medDoseval: "mcg", purpose: "Hypothyroidism", refillDate: "December 3, 2021", refillRem: "Refill Remaning: 1"),
] //Imagine more sample data here
```

I'm trying to sort values based on time range linked to the timeAt value.

```
ForEach (meds, id: \.id) { MedItem in
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 10.0){
}
```

If time is between 2am - 12pm then morning, 12pm - 3pm then noon, 3pm - 6pm evening, and 7pm - 2am then night. Some meds will not have a time and they need to be catoegorized in a different bucket.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Create a `@Observable`view model and do the sorting/grouping there. Then tell the view via a `@Published` property to update.

Comment: @Suff You can create different sections and sort the data based on it.

Comment: I’m very new to coding. Teaching myself how to code through tutorials and making my own app. Can you please help me with a solution. Much appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried so far to "...sort values based on time range linked to the timeAt value"?